# cordova is not using correct JAVA_Home location?

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am trying to build an android project with cordova but I am having trouble with the JDK.

I have made sure the path is correct and point to my JDK:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs;
C:\Mobile\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools; C:\Mobile\apache-ant-1.9.3-bin\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin; C:\Program
 Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin; C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
```

and when I run echo %JAVA_HOME% in my command prompt it shows

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin

but when I run the cordova build command it states JAVA_HOME Currently Set

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
```

I have also set a system variable under path called java_home and set it to

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin
```

I have also restarted my system since setting the path

can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who has the same problem I change my PATH to

> C:\Program Files\nodejs;
>   C:\Mobile\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools; C:\Mobile\apache-ant-1.9.3-bin\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin;
>
> %JAVA_HOME%\bin; %ANT_HOME%\bin

and this solved the problem

Comment: This has been killing me for hours. Thank you so much for getting me to a solution!